# What should I do with an off-topic question that has an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742870/background-not-changing-using-gsettings-from-cron) appeared in my review queue.

It begins by stating that it relates to Oracle Linux, which isn't Ubuntu and therefore off-topic.

But it has an accepted answer.

Do I flag it as off-topic anyway, or just leave it, on the off chance that it might be useful for someone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### An exceptional situation

I was almost going to ask the same question, since I answered the linked question accidentally, not noticing it was off-topic (my eye fell on gnome, in reflex I assumed it was on-topic)

In general, it should be marked as off-topic of course, accepted or not, since it simply *is* off-topic. In this case however, I decided *not* to.

#### Why I didn't mark it as off-topic

In many answers on AU, editing `gsettings` is done from `cron` incorrectly, and obviously untested by the answerer. The missing environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` makes the answer(s) in question not work (by definition).

Since *the answer* in your linked question is on topic, and applicable on many on-topic situations, I decided it would be a shame to have the question marked off-topic, for a reason that turns out to be irrelevant to the question (OP using Oracle Linux). We should not "throw the baby away, together with the bathwater" as we say in the Netherlands.

I consider this an exceptional situation however.

Comment: What if I edit out the mention of Oracle Linux, thus making it an on-topic general question about gsettings?

Comment: @CarlH Excellent idea, I'd say *in this case* we can, since it is proven to be irrelevant.

Comment: How are we throwing out the baby with the bathwater here? Remember this is *closing* the question, not deleting it. And closed questions with  accepted, upvoted answers aren't automatically deleted either. The baby remains with us.

Comment: Sure, but what is the use of having it marked as off-topic, while it is on-topic with a little edit. Being marked as off-topic degrades the question, while the (solution to the) issue is of some importance to a broader range of situations. Browsing through a (possibly long) list of answers, I would skip off-topic questions  
unknowingly more easily. Rules are important, unless they do not serve their goal, or even work against them.

Comment: Well it is a soft call, but, IMHO I see this site as Ubuntu specific. IMHO it is best to move more generic questions to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions as it is more likely to help those with generic questions on unix SE , but at the end of the day, I am not sure it matters. I tend to favor the close as off topic as it is not Ubuntu specific and the answer stays,

Comment: @bodhi.zazen my impression is then that we can move appr. 80% of the questions here to other se sites, maybe more.

Comment: Probably, but when the OP is not using Ubuntu IMHO they are better served by moving the question as is the case with this question rather then continuing to attempt to receive support here. In the case where they are asking a general question but using Ubuntu, leave it here. Again sort of a soft call, but the OP is using Oracle Linux, so next question is more likely to be off topic. When they are using Ubuntu the next question is more likely on topic, so IMHO the deciding factor is where should they be directed for future support ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I must say my perspective is the question and the q/a combination, not so much the person who asks, nor what he will do or not in future.

Comment: And that is why it is a good thing that 5 votes are required for moderation so as to avoid extremes or moderation by just one person.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen agreed.